# Machine storage vs join

Tags: mysql

I have a user account page that has a list of the posts my friends are making. Instead of using a join on my friends table to select the posts, would it be possible to store my friends ID's in local memory and select from posts where the set of local friends ID's includes the posters I'd. Basically just store something in local memory so I don't have to use a join.

-Local, cache, cookies [1,2,3,4,5]

-Select from posts where above set includes the posterId.

And if they decide to remove it from say local storage just iterate over friends and store another set.

...?

Comment: With proper indexing, the join should be just as performant. As it requires less complexity, I'd avoid overcomplicating this (and introducing new security holes, like a user changing their local storage to include other users' IDs they don't have permissions to).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about obfuscating it and storing in some strange place. The only thing I'm worried about is the probability that the friends table will have more values because you know, one person could have 2000 friends. Where one person could have 5 posts. Thank you

Comment: Thousands of developers have spent probably hundreds of thousands of hours ensuring relational databases handle that sort of scenario efficiently. Reinventing the wheel tends to result in a shoddier wheel.

Comment: How heavy is the IN operation one one piece vs 2000.

Comment: Joins, if properly indexed, are very performant, even with large numbers of relationships.

Comment: This negates you from having to query people that aren't your friends. And if you don't have a lot of friends and there are a ton of friends in the table then, I think this is better. Because using the In operation on 5 friends should be a little bit faster than searching 20 million rows where you only need five pieces of information. And for each of those five pieces you are querying an entire table. Where you could have just selected from a table using the IN operation of cached results that are updated on the fly. And security I don't think is a concern in this case.

Comment: Why are you asking here if you don't want to listen to the answers you get?

Comment: its not that i don't want to listen, i just want a different argument

Comment: Again, with the right indexes and logic, nothing you're doing requires "searching 20 million rows". That's what indexes are for. When you do the join, the query builder will use the join to limit the number of rows it has to look at.

Comment: hey ceejayoz, unfortunately I can no longer ask questions. not sure if it was because of my previous remarks. I just wanted to apologize and please ask for my account to be reactivated. I will make an assertive effort to not post any more inappropriate questions and or comments and will also delete this post.

Comment: I don't know what platform you're referring to; StackOverflow? If so, I'm not a moderator/admin, and I can't see anything in this thread that'd have triggered a suspension here. You also wouldn't be able to post comments...

Comment: it says i cant ask questions anymore

Comment: Nothing to do with me, nor do I have any visibility into it. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: no worries. pretty ridiculous that i'd get banned over one question in months of me using the platform. This is seriously an interesting community.